# Is it possible to use th-field to retrieve the value of a list in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-el

I am creating a page in thymeleaf where I retrieve a list from my controller to mount a table, in this table there is a selection field where I retrieve a list of values ​​but I am not able to display the value that is already being retrieved of the database can help me? Please!

I already tried to use the following commands but could not recover the value:

```
th:field="*{valoresAtributo[__${stat.index}__].valorUsuario}"
```

I receive the following error: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attribute.

```
<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered"  id="dataTable">
    <thead>             
        <tr><th colspan="4">Valores dos Atributos</th></tr>             
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr class="text-black">
            <td rowspan="2"> Atributo</td>
            <td rowspan="2"> Local</td>
            <td>Aplicação</td>              
            <td>Usuário</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="vlAppl"></td>               
            <td id="vlUser"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="valorAtributo, stat : ${valoresAtributo}">
            <td th:text="${valoresAtributo[__${stat.index}__].nomeAtributo}"></td>
            <td th:text="${valoresAtributo[__${stat.index}__].valorLocal}"></td>
            <td th:text="${valoresAtributo[__${stat.index}__].valorAplicaco}"></td>
            <td>
             <select class="form-control col-md-10" th:field="*{valoresAtributo[__${stat.index}__].valorUsuario}">
                    <option th:each="option : ${T(com.jequiti.JequitiIntegrador.controller.AtributoController).test(valorAtributo.sqlValidacao)}"
                                                th:value="${{option.valorAtributo}}"
                                                th:text="${option.significadoAtributo}">
                                        </option>
                </select>
             </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

```
@RequestMapping(value="/seguranca/atributo/valores", params = {"atributo","siteOpt","applOpt","userOpt","aplicacao","usuario"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initAttributeValuesFormFilter(@RequestParam("atributo") Long idAtributo, @RequestParam("siteOpt") Integer idNivel1, @RequestParam("applOpt") Integer idNivel2, @RequestParam("userOpt") Integer idNivel3, @RequestParam("aplicacao") String aplicacao, @RequestParam("usuario") String usuario, Model model)
    {
        Integer userId = 0;

        if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(usuario))
            userId = userServiceImpl.findIdUsuarioByFantasia(usuario).intValue();

        List<ValoresAtributoView> valoresAtributo = buscaValoresAtributos(idAtributo, idNivel1, idNivel2, idNivel3, 0, userId);

        model.addAttribute("opUsuarios", userServiceImpl.findAllActiveUsers());
        model.addAttribute("opAtributos", atributoService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("valoresAtributo",valoresAtributo);

        return "/valoresAtributo";
    }
```

I expected the field to display the value that is currently in the database and the options in the list of values.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `th:field` if you are using `th:object` in a parent `<form />` tag.  (Which isn't clear from the HTML you posted -- but you probably are not since your are adding `valoresAtributo` directly as a model attribute.)

If you wish to show a preselected `<option>` but without using `th:object` and `th:field` you should instead use the `th:selected` attribute which should evaluate to `true` or `false` based on if that option should be selected.  It should look something like this:

```
<select class="form-control col-md-10">
    <option
        th:each="option : ${T(com.jequiti.JequitiIntegrador.controller.AtributoController).test(valorAtributo.sqlValidacao)}"
        th:value="${{option.valorAtributo}}"
        th:text="${option.significadoAtributo}"
        th:selected="${valorAtributo.valorUsuario == option.valorAtributo}" />
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

My way to retrieve list using thymeleaf:

For example list `users` with list of `User` entity getting to html page:

```
@GetMapping("/parsing/explorer")
public ModelAndView parsing(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("show");
    modelAndView.addObject("users", generateUsersList());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

`show.html` example:

```
<table class="w3-table-all w3-card-4">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="user : ${users}"> 
            <td th:text="${user.getId()}"></td>
            <td th:text="${user.getName()}"></td>
            <td th:text="${user.getLastName()}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

So list of `User` (`users`) is assigned to the variable `user` in string `<tr th: every = "user: $ {users}">`

In the next block of code, we can also call the "User" fields the same way as `java` using getters, but Thymeleaf also allows you to refer to the fields: `user.id/ user.name`....

---

**Determining variable in the `select` block:**

```
    <select name="userFromHtml" id=userId required>
        <option th:each="user: ${users}">
            <title th:text="${user.getLastName()} + ' ' + ${user.getName()} + ' ' + ${user.getIdIO}" th:value="${user.getId()}"/>
        </option>
    </select>
```

in this case is necessary to determine `th:value` in `title` block: `th:value="${user.getId()}"`. So, in controller is passed variable `userFromHtml` with value `id` of selected user.

PS Although Thymeleaf allows you to define variable in direct, I prefer to use getters for data getting.

Comment: Hello my friend! first of all thanks for your reply and for being tempted to help me with my problem.

In your example how would you use a select-option retrieving the value that is in the database?

I tried to use th: field but I'm not trying to succeed.

Comment: @eduardosouza, hello friend). I have already added a part of the `select` code - block example. I use this path in my projects. If necessary, I can provide a git link for you.

Comment: @eduardosouza what is type of collection in `valoresAtributo`?

Comment: is of type java.util.List

Comment: @eduardosouza, so you just have to follow the example below. If this helps, please accept this answer as helpful.

Comment: Hello my friend!
That's the mistake I'm getting.  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'valorUsuario' available as request attribute

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @eduardosouza, may be you do not determine `valorUsuario` variable in controller? `@RequestParam String valorUsuario`

Comment: Many thanks for your help, @Metroids response worked.                                    
Thank you all!